# setOnItemClickListener not called in onCreatView method?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I am developing first android apps and I have a fragment class which extends `SherlockListFragment`. When I set `setOnItemClickListener` in `onCreateView` and implement `onItemClick` I'm getting no response when I click on a row(list). list display properly in my apps. I want when user click on row form `listview` my another activity will call. I goggled lot but not got proper answer. 
I can't understand where is the problem. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in following code?

following is the my code

```
public class ResidentialFragActivity extends SherlockListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle saved) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_list,container, false);
    resListviewId = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    linearProgress = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
    projectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    new LoadProjects().execute();
    resListviewId.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent href = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), ProjectDetailActivity.class);

            // send project id to project detail activity to get list of Phases under that project
            String proj_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.projectId)).getText().toString();

            href.putExtra("proj_id", proj_id);     
            getSherlockActivity().startActivity(href);
        }
    });
    return view;
}


//inner class for network operation
private class LoadProjects extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        linearProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //call webservice
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        linearProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ListAdapter projAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                projectList, R.layout.project_list_item, 
                new String[] {PROJ_ID,PROJ_NAME,EDIT_RIGHTS}, new int[] 
                        {R.id.projectId,R.id.projectName,R.id.projectSubName});
        //updating the UI
        setListAdapter(projAdapter);
    }
        }
}
```

following is the layout for listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"     
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:dividerHeight="1.5dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/divider" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you try adding android:clickable="true" to your listview

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onListItemClick` instead of instead of `resListviewId.setOnItemClickListener` .. as you are setting the adapter to the default one in  `setListAdapter(projAdapter);`

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent href = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), ProjectDetailActivity.class);

        // send project id to project detail activity to get list of Phases under that project
        String proj_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.projectId)).getText().toString();

        href.putExtra("proj_id", proj_id);     
        startActivity(href);
}
```

Comment: I did already used getListView().setOnItemClickListener but encountered Exception..

Comment: Exception like java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ojaswitech.bookinscape/com.ojaswitech.bookingscape.ProjectFragActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
E/AndroidRuntime(455): at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)

Comment: move the getListView().setOnItemClickListener into onActivityCreated method

Comment: I moved getListView().setOnItemClickListener into onActivityCreated but not working.

Comment: Now no exception, list is properly displaying but doesn't call another activity ..

Comment: add a log inside onItemClick to make sure it enters or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29474/discussion-between-nilesh-wani-and-nunu)